# How to add new service application with Central Adminstration

Tags: web-part, central-administration, excel-services, service-application, business-data-catalog

I want to excel document into my webpart in sharepoint 2013. First, I added a webpart in my page as follows. 
[image]

Then I clicked "Click here to open the tool pane." and I added workbook URL and OK. But I get error as follow.

[image]

I researched this error on the internet.  I found a solve. I did the following steps. But when I want to manage service connections,  I didn't found any application to select.

1. Open the Central administration
2. Application management
3. Manage web applications
4. Select the web application where your site resides underneath
5. Manage service connections
6. Select the Excel Services Application
7. Click OK

[image]

How can I add new service applications?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Central Administration, in the Application Management section, click Manage service applications.

On the Manage Service Applications page, click the Service Applications tab to enable the ribbon.

In the Create group of the ribbon, click New, and then click the service you want to create.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I've added excel service by following the steps. And I tried to run my page. But I still got the following error. 
"We don't know what happened, but somethnig went wrong. Could you please try that again?" Error id: ......"   @Aanchal